# How do I define a CloudFront Origin Group in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I want to define a CloudFront [Origin Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html) inside my CloudFormation `yaml` file.

How do I do this?  Or is it not yet supported by [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html)?

I always have trouble finding a definitive answer if service X feature Y is supported by CloudFormation.  My current go to is looking at the [Resource Types reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-cloudfront.html), and drilling down until I find what I'm looking for.  If anyone knows of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 3/15/2020**

This [has been released](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/65#issuecomment-596959898).  See [the updated CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origingroup.html).

**Original Answer**

It isn't supported yet.  AWS on 11/25/18 said:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=878667#878667

> CloudFormation does not support origin groups yet. We have heard this from other customers as well and it is added to our feature backlog. However, we don't have a timeline to offer at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Still, cloudformation is not supporting this feature. Date: 16-July-19

You can achieve this with AWS custom resources and  Lambda-Backed custom resources.

Below are the links for your reference.

Custom Resources -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation now supports [specifying Origin Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html) inside a CloudFront distribution configuration.  However, as far as I can tell you can not (yet) create an origin group in CloudFormation

Comment: But there is no option to specify the primary and secondary origins for the origin group. Which means cloudformation still do not support the OriginGroup functionality.

Comment: Orly? thats crazy